# How to call web service from browser using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code that call an online web service, I run this code from browser but it always give error and run error function, is there a port to open to call web service from a browser using Javascript

```
$.ajax(
{
  type: 'POST',
  url:'https://www.arsel.qa/arselservicesstg/GeneralServices.asmx/GetMobileConfiguration',
  data: "key=some value",
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: function (response) {},
  error: function (error) {
    alert(error + "error");
  }
}) // adding missing code (probably an issue adding the code here)
```

Comment: the alert shows:  [Object Object] error

Comment: Try console.log(error)

Comment: Try changing your `alert` to `console.log(error)` and looking in the console

Comment: this is the error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: The URL you are using in `ajax` is wrong

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: is the GetMobileConfiguration method is public and has 'web method' attribute?

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Comment: You havent loaded jQuery on your page

Comment: yes i can access the web service from my android and blackberry phone

Comment: @Malo http://stackoverflow.com/a/29729383/2025923 Might be helpful

Comment: i replace https with http and still get this error only Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: why my jquery is not defined ??

Comment: there is some problem with url

Comment: the CORS is enabled on web serviceand i try to call the web service from java android app and its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the data property as:

```
data: { 'Key' : 'value' },
```

Comment: Its Working thank you a loooooooooooooooooooooooot:D